# В чем разница байндинга с Path и без него?

Tags: xaml, uwp

В примера встречается как

```
Свойство={x:Bind Property}
```

так и

```
Свойство={x:Bind Path=Property}
```

Объясните, в чем разница? В документации так написано, что возникает ощущение, что разницы нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и есть, разницы нет. `Path` — свойство «по умолчанию».

Из [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#property-path):

> You can mention the name of the `Path` property explicitly: `{Binding Path=...}`. Or you can omit it: `{Binding ...}`.

---

**Дополнение:** Существуют редкие случаи, при которых эти два синтаксиса всё же не одно и то же. Например, для такого кода:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="Path1">Name</sys:String>
    <PropertyPath x:Key="Path2">Name</PropertyPath>
</Window.Resources>
```

вот эти объявления работают:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding {StaticResource Path1}}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path={StaticResource Path2}}"/>
```

а эти приводят к исключению:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding {StaticResource Path2}}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path={StaticResource Path1}}"/>
```

Разница в том, что при синтаксисе без `Path` вызывается конструктор `Binding` со строковым аргументом, а свойство `Path` имеет тип `PropertyPath`. Обычно при присвоении вызывается конвертер типов, но использование `StaticResource` блокирует это.

Ещё немного отличий [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9383001/276994).

Comment: Прикол в том, что иногда разница есть. :) Не знаю, починили ли баг.

Comment: @Squidward: Вспомните пример? Было бы круто.

Comment: Вроде, биндинги на прикреплённые свойства внутри шаблонов, возможно, ещё какие-то условия.

Comment: @Squidward: А разница синтаксическая (один из подходов не компилируется) или семантическая (компилируются оба, но результат не одинаковый)?

Comment: Без `Path=` в рантайме ошибки вываливаются, вроде. Не помню.

Comment: @Squidward: _Большинство_ ответов на многочисленные вопросы по теме на en.SO говорят, что разницы нет. Кроме [этого](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9383001/276994). (Попробую разобраться и обновить ответ.)